# Set state of parent with react Router from Route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a page where on top there is a step progress bar (something like [this](http://kodhus.com/newsite/step-progress-bar-css-only/)). In the center of the page there is some content that depends on the current step.
To manage the step I have a fixed component with the step bar and a switch with some routes (/step1 /step2).
When I want pass from step1 to step 2 I have to call `history.push()` in this way I can easily change route.

My problem is that I cannot update the step bar from step2 because even if I pass a function to the parent react retrives me an error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

The structure of my code is the following:

COMPONENT: Parent

```
changeParentState(){
    this.setState({
       stateToChange: "something-changed"
    });
}
render(){
    return(
        <div> here the stepBar to update </div>
        <Switch>
             <Route path = '/step1' render = {() => <Step1Component attributes = {this.someAttributes}}/>
             <Route path = '/step2' render = {() => <Step2Component attributes = {this.changeParentState.bind(this)}}/>
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

COMPONENT Step1

```
render(){
  return(
     <button onClick = {() => {history.push({pathname: '/step2'})}}>next</button>
  )
}
```

COMPONENT Step2

```
constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.props.changeParentState();  //error in parent when updating state
}
```

Here I semplified the problem, I hope I don't omit some code that generates my problem

Comment: Kinda confusing , do you really need to switch routes? is it on a different container? or can you just render the components needed and not use routes?

Comment: try logging this.props on component 2 , check if changeParentState is inside the component

Comment: Move `this.props.changeParentState();` inside `componentDidMount`. This may not solve your issue, but its anyways an issue in the code. In general, don't perform any mutations through constructor.

Comment: Parent's render->Step2's constructor->Parent's changeParentState->Parent' render....

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call the function from the constructor 
try

```
componentWillMount(){
  this.props.changeParentState();
}
```

i never used attributes before but i prefer

```
<Step2Component changeParentState = {this.changeParentState.bind(this)}}/>
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` is preferable, as React may not decide to mount the component.